# Crystal Reports for VS not Expanding Text

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

Please see these two images. Firstly in the design view, you can see the orange and green boxes go all the way to the next field. And in the green you can see the last word there is "the".

[image]

Yet, when the report is printed and populated by the C# application, it doesn't go to the end of the box. Instead it leaves about a centimetre or two and then wraps (where the red arrow is).

[image]

Anyone know why? We want the words to go to the end of the boxes.

Comment: YOU MAY USE CANGROW PROPERTY IN CRYSTAL REPORT FORMATE OBJECT.

Comment: @UmairRasheed, please refrain from using all caps while posting comments.

Comment: CanGrow only makes it grow vertically down the page. we want it to use up the entire object horizontally